# Removing personal email addresses from questions?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, editing, profile-page

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/217286/73835) (before it was deleted by the votes of six non-moderators) included the user's personal email address.

To me this seems to work against GIS SE because if the questioner decides to act on the advice privately then the site loses out on answering this question/getting the a right answer.  Although this question ([How to combine rows in attribute table using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89953)) already has several answers, should this kind of behaviour be discouraged, and should the email be removed?

I've had a look over the help topics but I couldn't find anything that mentioned not including email addresses in question/answers.

Comment: Possible relevant posts: [How do I contact other users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users); and [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ...should the email be removed?

Yes, personal information goes in the user profile page.

Posts must be kept as clean as possible, i.e, without user signatures, salutations, and other kinds of unrelated messages with the Q/A content.

Comment: This approach agrees with that advocated at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148399/215590